# Best way to have a conditional based on percentage error in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to have a loop in Python like this, which makes the `if` statement execute when the value is less than the lower threshold or greater than upper threshold:-

```
for i in x_range_original:
  for j in range(0,16):
    lower_threshold = min(df_log[:,j])
    upper_threshold = max(df_log[:,j])

    if df_log[i,j] < lower_threshold or df_log[i,j] > upper_threshold:
      print("Error detected")
```

However, what I would like to do is have conditions like this:-

```
if df_log[i,j] within 5 % of lower_threshold or df_log[i,j] within 5 % of upper_threshold:
  print("Error detected")
```

I know that this accomplished using long statements within the conditional and multiple conditions. But, is there a neat way (say a function which can do the part of within 5 %) to accomplish this, or any way we can do this in minimal lines of code?

Comment: what do you mean by within 5%. Can you give an example?

Comment: @AAA I mean +- 5 %. So, if the value is either 5 % above or below the lower or upper threshold, I want to execute the if statement.

Comment: @jchat Write a function that calculates ±5% of the threshold and compares the other number to it.

Comment: @wjandrea yes, as I mentioned in the question, I know that we can do this using multiple lines of code (which a function would probably need), so I was looking for a one liner, especially the logic to do this within the conditional block. AAA's answer helped, but anyways I am upvoting your comment as it is also the second possible way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chained comparisons:

```py
# lt,ut = lower_threshold, upper_threshold
if((0.95*lt < df_log[i,j] < 1.05*lt) or (0.95*ut < df_log[i,j] < 1.05*ut)):
          print("Error detected")
```

We can even make it more pythonic as @wjandrea suggests below;

```py
if any(0.95*t < df_log[i,j] < 1.05*t for t in [lt, ut]):
          print("Error detected")
```

If by any chance, `lower_threshold` or `upper_threshold` could be negative then:

```
x,lt,ut = map(abs, [df_log[i,j], lower_threshold, upper_threshold])
if any(0.95*t < x < 1.05*t for t in [lt, ut]):
          print("Error detected")
```

Comment: Interesting answer and logic. Thank you! this was what I was looking for, doing everything in the minimal possible code.

Comment: Sort the mathematics and logic first, then write the program next... Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method to check if something is within some range is to check the value of the absolute difference. You can do the same here, checking the percent error. In this case, `abs(df_log[i, j] - lower_threshold)` will give you the absolute error between the two values, and then you can divide by the threshold to get the percentage error. Then you directly compare that to the allowable error in percent. In general I find it more expressive and less error-prone than chained comparisons. Compare the two methods:

With chained comparisons:

```
def within(val, thresh, margin):
    return (1 - margin) * thresh < val < (1 + margin) * thresh
```

With percentage error:

```
def within(val, thresh, margin):
    return abs((val - thresh) / thresh) < margin
```

Note that these aren't exactly equivalent--- the first method actually fails for negative threshold values, because the comparators would need to be swapped. Thus the second method is more consistent.

Comment: Implemented: `if any(within(df_log[i,j], t, 0.05) for t in (lower_threshold, upper_threshold)):`

Comment: Sure, but should be `0.05` not `5`. And the two thresholds need to be in a collection.

Answer (score 1):

My python is not that good, so I don't get your code, but I do know this function can work for your case.

The Python abs() method calculates the absolute value of a number. The abs() method takes in one parameter: the number whose absolute value you want to calculate.

If you want your threshold to be 5%, then

```
if abs(x/y) > 0.05
    # do something
```

link to the website here:https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-absolute-value/